# Google Analytics Enhanced E-commerce not working with cross-domain tracking

Tags: google-analytics

Previously, our enhanced ecommerce tracking was working properly as follows:

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'ec');
@foreach(var prod in Model.Purchases){
    <text>
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
        'id': '@prod.PolNumber',
        'name': '@prod.Name',
        'brand': '@prod.Brand',
        'quantity': '@prod.Quantity'
    });</text>
}
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
    'id': '@Model.id',
    'revenue': '@Model.TotalValue'
});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

However, once we tried to add cross-domain tracking, which modified the code by changing the first line into three lines:

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'auto', { 'allowLinker': true });
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['mynewwebsite.com']);
```

And then was followed by the remaining code:

```
ga('require', 'ec');
...
```

All the way to the end.  The code successfully does the cross-domain tracking, but the e-commerce piece isn't showing up in Google Analytics.  We don't want to set up two separate trackers, and retrograding to the older e-commerce option Google Analytics provides isn't preferable either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer, at least on the surface, is NOT code-related.  As it so happens, the page redirect that normally would have pointed to this page, thus rendering the analytics code, was changed recently.  As a result, the page that contains this analytics code was never being called, and so the analytics was not working.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct ga method call is "require", but you have "required":

```
ga('require', 'ec');
```

Comment: I made a mistake when transferring my code over.  It should say 'require'.  That is what is currently in the code.  But thank you for being observant!